# React + Meteor keyed object warning

Tags: meteor, reactjs

How do I get rid of this warning? If I delete `task.created` there is no warning. Can't figure this one out. See my code example below:

`Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.`

```
ShowAllPosts = React.createClass({

  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  getMeteorData() {
    // This function knows how to listen to Meteor's reactive data sources,
    // such as collection queries
    return {
      // Returns an array with all items in the collection
      tweets: Posts.find().fetch().reverse()
    }
  },

  render() {
    var showHTML = this.data.posts.map(function (task) {
      return (
        <div key={task._id}>
          <img className="profile-pic" src="images/puppy.jpeg" />
          {task.content}
          <br />
          Date: {task.created}, <a href="{task._id}">Get Link</a>, id: {task._id}
          <hr />
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <ul>
        <hr />
        {/* Access the data from getMeteorData() on this.data */}
        { showHTML }
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: What does task.created hold? I'm wondering if it's because it's a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `task.created` is a Date object.

React isn't casting dates to strings automatically, so you need to write something like `{task.created.toString()}` or use package like [moment](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment) to format your date.